# Drawing without replacement from a bag until...

Tags: probability, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Elements are drawn randomly without replacement from a bag with $n$ unique elements until $1 \le k \le n$ unique elements have been drawn.

For $1 \le i \le n$, given there were $a[i]$ in the bag initially, **what is the probability, $p[i]$, that at least one of the $i^{\text{th}}$ element is among the $k$ drawn?**

Trivial cases:

$k=1$:  $p[i]=\frac{a[i]}{S}$, where $S = a[1]+a[2]+...+a[n]$. (only one draw necessary.)

$k=n:$  $p[i]=1$ (all elements are drawn at least once.)